# Visual Studio 2019 and iOS: native linking failed

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I have my `Xamarin` solution in `Visual Studio 2019` for `Windows`. I can build the solution for `UWP` and `Android` but I receive a lot of errors when I try to compile the project for `iOS`. Here the list of errors:

[image: Visual Studio 2019 native linking failed]

Generally, the errors are similar to the following:

> Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _kFIRAppDiagnosticsNotification. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

On my Mac, I have the latest updates for the `OS` and `XCode`. `Visual Studio 2019 for Mac` is installed.

I checked the `iOS Build` and I changed the `Supported Architectures` with:

[image: Visual Studio]

If I use the default value `ARM64`, Visual Studio compiles the solution but at the end of the copying on the device, there is an error:

> APIInternalError: Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.ReCcst/extracted/WordBankEasy.iOS.app/WordBankEasy.iOS

[image: Failed]

### Update

I noticed the problem is coming from `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.AdMob` version 7.38.0: if I remove it, I can deploy my app on a `iOS` device.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you tried delete obj and bin folder, clean and rebuild your project? After you use the default value ARM64, you can try to delete the app on the phone/simulator you installed before and then run your project. Also you can try change the linker behavior to Don't link.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes, I did all of those. Nothing fixed the problem. Also, I tried to reboot both laptops.

Comment: Just google "xamarin firoptions" to find the github.com bug report.

Comment: I think I resolved the problem. I removed all `Firebase` libraries and added only `Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds` and now I can run the project